# Calling IBOutlet from other class Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm working on a menubar application and now I want to make a feature that when you uncheck a checkbox from the preferences a menu item will hide.

The problem is that the preferences is another class then the AppDelegate and the checkbox is in the Preferences.xib and the menu items are in the MainMenu.xib

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I fixed it by using this code,

```
[[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate] iboutlet] setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: Bind `hidden` of the menu item to a property of the App Delegate or the Shared User Defaults Controller.

Comment: @Willeke how am i able to do that, im new to cocoa and objective-c

Comment: Ok, start with hiding the menu item in code. Read [Introduction to Application Menus and Pop-up Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/MenuList.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000032-SW1). Or let the app delegate (`[NSApp delegate]`) hide the menu item.

Comment: @Willeke How could I let the app delegate hide the menu item, this might be a really stupid question but I just don't get it

Comment: The App Delegate is in the same xib as the menu so you can create an outlet and connect the menu item. Create a method which hides the menu item and call this method.

Comment: Additionally you can use a binding to the user defaults. I assume that the preferences will be stored in the user defaults.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad yes I do store the preferences to the user defaults but how could I create a binding.

Comment: Do you store the value of the checkbox somewhere?

Comment: @Willeke yes I store it to the NSUserDefaults

Comment: @Willeke thanks for your help and time, i fixed it now with help of avvensis and your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift lang

```
if let appDelegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
      appDelegate.customMenuItem.hidden = true // or false
}
```

where `customMenuItem` is outlet of your menu item.

Comment: Im using objective-c

Comment: Is it difficult to translate? I don't know Objective-C too. `NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` is most important part of the answer that will help you get access to the outlet.

Comment: Translated it to obj-c and it worked thanks so much!